# Block device suddenly full; can't identify a single file as culprit and SMART shows no drive errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk-space-utilization, ext4, troubleshooting

### Setup

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Dell PowerEdge R820
- [PERC H710] 2x Virtual Drives (RAID-1 Boot, RAID-0 Work Drive)
- Everything been fine for 6 months
- No preceeding even, just suddenly, drive full.

### Details...

This machine is used for plotting Chia (cryptocurrency) - it's been working away for months without issue.

I noticed the plotting process crashed (bladebit) - which is pretty uncommon, happens maybe once every 2 months - so I went to fire it back up and immediately started getting `device full` types of errors.

I fired off a quick `df -h` to see what was going on, and got this:

```
Filesystem          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                252G     0  252G   0% /dev
tmpfs                51G  2.9M   51G   1% /run
/dev/sda2           549G  512G  8.7G  99% /
tmpfs               252G  4.0K  252G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs               252G     0  252G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1           511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                51G     0   51G   0% /run/user/1000
<... SNIP ...>
```

`/dev/sda2` is the boot drive - it's actually a RAID-1 (2-disk) Virtual Disk handled by the H710 RAID card in the server, but I don't think that's terribly relevant.

**NORMALLY** this drive is 3% full, it only has bootable Ubuntu Server 20.04 installed on it and nothing else.

I had to erase the tmp file in root and a few other garbage files to free up space enough to get things to function again, but it's sitting at dang near full.

I followed countless "find the biggest file on your server" tips from here and around the web, for example [this one](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-largest-file-in-directory-recursively-using-find-du/), with the command `sudo du -a / 2>/dev/null | sort -n -r | head -n 20` returning:

```
$ sudo du -a / 2>/dev/null | sort -n -r | head -n 20
[sudo] password for user: 
1010830919685   /
1010823681740   /mnt
<...SNIP...>
```

Ok so something huge sitting in `/` apparently? A simple `ls` shows nothing of interest in there:

```
$ ls -lFa /
total 84
drwxr-xr-x   20 root root  4096 Jan 12 17:45 ./
drwxr-xr-x   20 root root  4096 Jan 12 17:45 ../
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root     7 Aug 24 08:41 bin -> usr/bin/
drwxr-xr-x    4 root root  4096 Jan  6 06:22 boot/
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root  4096 Sep 28 14:04 cdrom/
drwxr-xr-x   21 root root  6920 Jan  5 16:05 dev/
drwxr-xr-x  105 root root  4096 Jan  5 01:54 etc/
drwxr-xr-x    3 root root  4096 Sep 28 14:18 home/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root     7 Aug 24 08:41 lib -> usr/lib/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root     9 Aug 24 08:41 lib32 -> usr/lib32/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root     9 Aug 24 08:41 lib64 -> usr/lib64/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root    10 Aug 24 08:41 libx32 -> usr/libx32/
drwx------    2 root root 16384 Sep 28 14:03 lost+found/
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root  4096 Aug 24 08:42 media/
-rw-r--r--    1 root root  6678 Jan  9 00:59 MegaSAS.log
drwxr-xr-x   64 root root  4096 Jan  5 01:48 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x    3 root root  4096 Nov 30 18:14 opt/
dr-xr-xr-x 1356 root root     0 Jan  3 04:40 proc/
drwx------    7 root root  4096 Nov 30 18:07 root/
drwxr-xr-x   34 root root  1100 Jan 12 08:04 run/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root     8 Aug 24 08:41 sbin -> usr/sbin/
drwxr-xr-x    9 root root  4096 Sep 28 22:06 snap/
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root  4096 Aug 24 08:42 srv/
dr-xr-xr-x   13 root root     0 Jan  3 04:40 sys/
drwxrwxrwt   13 root root  4096 Jan 12 17:15 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x   15 root root  4096 Aug 24 08:46 usr/
drwxr-xr-x   13 root root  4096 Aug 24 08:47 var/
```

Using `sudo ncdu -x /` ([link](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ncdu.1.html)) shows nothing interesting oddly enough:

```
    2.4 GiB [##########] /usr                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    1.5 GiB [######    ] /var
  732.5 MiB [##        ] /home
  202.8 MiB [          ] /boot
    5.5 MiB [          ] /opt
    5.4 MiB [          ] /etc
    1.9 MiB [          ] /root
  168.0 KiB [          ] /tmp
<...SNIP...>
```

Where is this ~510GB of used space sitting?

Firing off a `sudo lsof | grep deleted` to see if there is some giant file being held onto, gave me this:

```
systemd-j    1134                               root   36u      REG                8,2 134217728    5246838 /var/log/journal/771d7f1addf64a7b930191976176149e/system@ae2f8b2397c441f7a286d25144be755f-0000000000315312-0005d4e51ab8f8e9.journal (deleted)
unattende    3932                               root    3w      REG                8,2       113    5246631 /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-shutdown.log.1 (deleted)
unattende    3932    3943 gmain                 root    3w      REG                8,2       113    5246631 /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-shutdown.log.1 (deleted)
```

Ok so it's holding onto a 134mb journal file, but that still doesn't explain why suddenly there is 510GB of the drive being taken up.

I also tried some additional searches, like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/731542), and resulted in nothing helpful either.

I eventually used `megacli` to check the SMART data off the 2 drives in the RAID-0 array and they have 0 errors reported so it doesn't seem like the array got damaged.

Any ideas or additional digging tricks I might try to figure out what is sucking up that space?

**UPDATE #1** - I noticed when I typed `top` that `buff/cache` was almost exactly the size of the GB's that were being consumed on the root drive. I know that space isn't counted as `used`, but I decided to fire off a quick:

```
sudo sh -c "/usr/bin/echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

which took about 3mins to run but eventually returned - `top` now shows `buff/cache` as < 1k, BUT `df -h` shows no change in disk usage.

I had hoped it was a mystery cache file on disk or something like that.

Comment: UPDATE 2 - In the off chance I was "hiding" a massive file from myself by mounting on top of it, I `mount -o bind` my root dir to `/tmp/fake-root` to take a peek in the ROOT and `/mnt` directories just incase something was in there... didn't discover anything. This tip was from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198543/509866

Comment: UPDATE 3 - Fired off a `sudo find / -type f -printf '%s %p\n' 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied' | sort -nr | head -10` and unfortunately besides saying that `/proc/kcore` is like 100 EB, it didn't show me any other big files I didn't already know about.